# Reducing memory usage downloading file

Tags: python, azure

I have a python script where I'm downloading a file into memory and storing it into a variable.

```
stream = downloadBlob(blob_name_file)

def downloadBlob(blob_name_file: str):
    # creating container client to access container
        container_str_url = secret_client.get_secret("testString").value
        container_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_str_url)
    # blob client to access the specific blob
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob= blob_name_file)
        # downloading the blob to memory in bytes
        stream_downloader = blob_client.download_blob()
        stream = BytesIO()
        stream_downloader.readinto(stream)
        return stream
```

After I have that I put it into a dataframe

```
try:
        processed_df = pd.read_parquet(stream, engine='pyarrow')
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Once in the dataframe I go ahead and delete the stream variable to free up memory (or at least that's the goal)

```
del stream
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm still using up too much memory. I'm using Azure to run my script and am limited to ~2.5gb RAM. It can run fine on one machine without memory issues, but when I push this up to run on even just 2 machines with one instance, I'm hitting memory cap at times. The part of the code that I've outlined in this post is what I assume would use the most memory, the rest of the script just passes the dataframe around basically. I even reduce the dataframes' size and `del` the original.

My question is, is there a better way of doing what I'm doing at all? And is `del` doing what I believe it is doing? Because I'll be honest, even after adding `del` to my script, it didn't seem to affect memory usage much, if at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959077/free-memory-in-python)

Comment: @Donnie There is definitely something there that I can try. ```gc.collect()``` after the ```del``` 's. I will look into it tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion